# Cannot access docker daemon metrics at 172.18.0.1/metrics

Tags: docker

I exposed docker daemon at port 9323:

```
cat  /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "debug": true,
  "metrics-addr" : "127.0.0.1:9323",
  "experimental" : true
}
```

I can connect to `0.0.0.0:9323/metrics` and `127.0.0.1:9323/metrics`, both works fine but when I tried `172.18.0.1:9323/metrics`:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.18.0.1 port 9323: Connection refused

Here's my firewall rule set:

```
iptables -L | grep 9323
ACCEPT     tcp  --  172.18.0.0/16        anywhere             tcp dpt:9323
ACCEPT     udp  --  172.18.0.0/16        anywhere             udp dpt:9323
```

My `docker_gwbridge` IP:

```
ip -o addr show docker_gwbridge
5: docker_gwbridge    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global docker_gwbridge\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker_gwbridge    inet6 fe80::42:d0ff:fedb:2ba0/64 scope link \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Does changing the address in the config file to `"0.0.0.0:9323"` help?  That would also make the metrics endpoint accessible from off-host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `metrics-addr` setting to `0.0.0.0:9323`.

This setting tells the Docker daemon where to listen for inbound connections to serve up Prometheus-compatible metrics.  0.0.0.0 is a special IPv4 address here meaning "all interfaces".  If you specify a different address, the service will only be reachable on the network interface with that address.  In the case of 127.0.0.1, that's the host's `lo0` loopback interface, but in the case of Docker containers, inbound connections actually arrive via the artificial `docker0` interface.

The other important consequence of this is that this service will *also* be reachable from external hosts; it will be visible on your `eth0` or `en0` or `wlan0` interface as well.  You may need to update your firewall setup if you want to block this.

(You may recognize this address from two other Docker contexts.  Processes running inside containers need to be set to listen on 0.0.0.0 and not 127.0.0.1 for the same reason, so that they'll accept requests on the container's private artificial `eth0` interface from outside the container.  The `docker run -p` option publishes a port and takes an optional IP address that defaults to 0.0.0.0, but you can explicitly specify `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:...` to publish a port that's only reachable from host-native processes and not off-host and not from containers calling the host's IP address.)